# ¿Se puede considerar que "que sea a una persona de buen corazón" es una oración condicional?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

Tengo una duda: ¿Se puede considerar la frase en negrita como una oración condicional? (= si nos enamoramos, enamorémonos de una persona de buen corazón) ¿O es una oración (exclamativa) independiente en que se expresa deseo?

> ¡Puestos a amar, **que sea a una persona de buen corazón**!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una oración independiente en la que se expresa deseo.

El término "oración condicional" suele usarse para la circunstancia, con verbo, bajo la cual otra cosa podría suceder.

En esta oración, la circunstancia en todo caso sería "puestos a amar" y no "que sea a una persona de buen corazón". Nótese que la construcción de esta circunstancia no es una oración condicional, sino un ejemplo de lo que la Real Academia Española en el *Manual de la nueva gramática de la lengua española* llama "construcciones absolutas" (§38.6, pág. 734).

A la oración de la consecuencia que ocurre cuando la circunstancia acaece se le llama "la oración principal" (o (la) apódosis). (A la circunstancia también se le llama "prótasis".)

El origen de la común confusión de llamar la consecuencia "oración condicional" se debe al problema clásico de terminología en el que el tiempo "condicional" de los verbos ("haría", "harías"...) no aparece en oraciones condicionales.

Comment: ¡Qué buena primera respuesta! Bienvenido a [spanish.se] :)

Comment: Ay Renato, ¡genial! gracias, gracias, graciaaaassss : )